# How to add data from one listbox to another listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

The following data are displayed in listbox1. I want to pass items from listbox2 to listbox1. The result should be look as shown below (lb1).How can this be achieved? 
Many thanks for your help!

```
var itm = listBox2.Items[0].ToString();
          listBox1.Items.Add(itm);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuOhv.jpg)

Comment: Do you want a copy of the references (an entanglement of the items) or a duplication of the list ?

Comment: Each item in listbox1 are seperated by a comma. I would like to attach the item from listbox2 to the previous one in the same line (not among each other).

Comment: Do you mean like this? `string firstLine = listBox1.Items[0] as string; if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstLine)) listBox1.Items[0] = itm; else listBox1.Items[0] += "," + itm;`?

Comment: Correct!  That's works! Thank you very much, "mm8" : )

Answer (score 0):

Use `AddRange` Method. Try like:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(listBox2.Items);
```

Comment: That doesn’t work. Each item in listbox1 are seperated by a comma. I would like to attach the item from listbox2 to the previous one in the same line (not among each other) Thanks for your advice "apomene"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddRange`

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(listBox2.Items);
```

Or if you want an exact copy of what is in the other listbox without your old items.

```
listBox1.Items = listBox2.Items;
```

Comment: That doesn’t work. Each item in listbox1 are seperated by a comma. I would like to attach the item from listbox2 to the previous one in the same line (not among each other) Thanks for your advice,Martin